# How do Groovy Scripts interact with propertyMissing?

Tags: groovy

I writing a DSL that executes as a `Script`; it has various classes for various bits of syntax. e.g., for the "foo" keyword that takes a closure, I have a `FooSyntax` class and evaluate the closure "with" an instance of that syntax. This works fine, e.g.

```
bar = thing {} // make a thing 
baz = foo {
    mykeyword bar
}
```

passes the thing called bar to an invocation of `FooSyntax#mykeyword`.

I'm trying to add some better error messages for when there is an unknown variable reference.  This manifests as a `MissingPropertyException` so my current approach is to add a `propertyMissing` method to `FooSyntax`.  This works indeed for variables that are missing.

Unfortunately, it breaks the example above: `bar` becomes a missing property instead of falling through to the Binding. Why does adding a `propertyMissing` cause the `Binding` not to be consulted? (Does this have to do with the `Closure`'s resolve strategy?) How can I fix this?

You can play with this with a sample script at https://gist.github.com/1237768

Comment: Do you have your code that executes this script, so I can try it out and see if I can see what's wrong?

Comment: I added a link to a Gist you can play with. The script seems to hang on http://groovyconsole.appspot.com but runs on the command-line fine (I'm using 1.8.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall delegate my answer to the gist on which I commented. Basically, you should not be using the `with()` method to execute the closure against the `FooSyntax` delegate. For future reference, the standard approach is:

```
def foo(Closure cl) {
    def f = new FooSyntax()
    def c = cl.clone()
    c.delegate = f
    c.call()
}
```

You can fine tune the behaviour by changing the resolution strategy on the closure like so:

```
c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
```

but in this case you want the default `Closure.OWNER_FIRST` to ensure the binding is queried first.

Answer (score 0):

Since ***bar*** was not being declared (just assigned), it was hitting the property missing because there wasn't an already defined bar in the script or syntax classes.

In your example, I think you want to implement a ***methodMissing***.  In your scenario you are trying to call Foo.myKeyword with a non-Thing type.  So that is really a missing method and not a missing property.

I've changed your script, changing propertyMissing to methodMissing and adding def for foo and also defined bar as a String.

```
class Thing { }

class FooSyntax {
   def myKeyword(Thing t) { println "Hello Foo " + t.toString(); }    
   def methodMissing(String name, args) {
       println "no method named ${name} for ${args} exists"
   }
}

class ScriptSyntax {
    def foo(Closure cl) {
        def f = new FooSyntax();
        f.with cl
    }
    def thing() { new Thing()  }

    def dispatchKeyword(String methodName, Object args) {
       invokeMethod(methodName, args)
    }
}

def runner(String text) {
   def source = new GroovyCodeSource(text, "inlineScript", "inline.groovy")

   def script = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(source).newInstance(binding) as Script
   def dsl = new ScriptSyntax()
   script.metaClass.methodMissing = { name, args -> dsl.dispatchKeyword(name, args) }
   script.run()
}

runner("""def bar = thing()
def baz = "not a thing"
foo { myKeyword bar }
foo { myKeyword baz }""")

Output:
Hello Foo Thing@1038de7
no method named myKeyword for [not a thing] exists
```

Comment: I understand that if you add a `def`, it can work correctly.  However, I'd like to avoid having to introduce `def` to the users of the DSL if possible. I think what is happening is that there's some sort of default `propertyMissing` or `methodMissing` that is getting overridden?  Also, I want the error to read "no variable baz defined", not "no method named myKeyword".